# End span tag in cake php using Html helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, html-helper

How to end the tag in cake php

It is given in cake tutorial the below span tag will be formed by html helper, when text is given null.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->tag('span', null, array('class' => 'welcome'));?>
//Output
<span class="welcome">
```

But, here no idea about ending span tag.How can it be given html helper

```
<span class="welcome">
    //inner elements
</span>
```

Is there anything in cake php html helper to close any element tags like

```
<?php echo $this->Html->tag('span', 'close') ?>
```

will output as

```
</span> .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide an empty string `""`, instead of `null`, for the second parameter when calling the `tag` method. Otherwise, it just prints the start tag according to the [API docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/HTML.html#tag).

Comment: I know `<?php echo $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'welcome'));?>` this work. But I want to know the case when null is given in text.

Comment: You could use the ternary operator: `<?php echo $this->Html->tag('span', $text ?: '', array('class' => 'welcome'));?>` It uses the value of $text if $text evaluates to true, otherwise it uses the empty string.

Comment: Is there anything like `<?php echo $this->Html->tag('span', 'close') ?>` will output as `</span>` .

Comment: No, there is no such feature as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
<?php
echo $html->tag("span", null);
... whatever ...
echo $html->tag("/span", null);
?>
```